# Como faço para um contador em javascript que é executado por uma função começar a contar do ultimo numero que parou?

Tags: javascript

pessoal preciso fazer um contador que é executado por uma função em javascript, porém esse contador quando a função for ser executada de novo deverá começar de onde parou exemplo:

```
1
2 
3
4 
5 
6

terminou de executar a função.
```

executei a função de novo

```
7  
8  
9  
10
```

precisaria fazer algo assim em javascript alguém pode me ajudar segue o código que estou usando, detalhe como vocês poderão ver no código ao retornar do ajax a pagina redireciona.

```
let numeros = [];
let max = 100000;

//cadastra as informações selecionadas pelo cliente
function cadastrar(){
    //variaveis com os valores dos campos digitados pelo usuário
    var action = "cad_cliente";
    var ok = "#btnOK";
    var clean = "#btnClean";
    var radio = ":checkbox";
    var msgbox =".tab span";
    var msgbox1 =".conf span";
    var color;  

    var n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * max);
        while(numeros.indexOf(n) >= 0){
            n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * max);
        }
        numeros.push(n);

    if($(radio).is(":checked")){
    var pacote = document.getElementsByClassName('data');

        for (var i = 0; i < pacote.length; i++){

            if ( pacote[i].checked ) {
                var valores = pacote[i].value;

                var j = valores.split(';');
                var pedido  = $("#pedido_"+j).val();

                if(pedido == 0){
                    $(msgbox)
                        .html("A QUANTIDADE DO PEDIDO NÃO PODE SER 0")
                        .removeClass()
                        .addClass("alert alert-danger")
                        .show();
                    return false;
                } 
                var cod_cli = $("#cod_cli").val();
                var email   = $("#email_cli").val();
                var nome    = $("#nome_cli").val();
                var cnpj    = $("#cnpj_cli").val();
                var end     = $("#end_cli").val();
                var bairro  = $("#bairro").val();
                var numero  = $("#numero").val();
                var cep     = $("#cep_cli").val();
                var cidade  = $("#cid_cli").val();
                var sub = nome.substr(0,6);
                var replace = sub.replace(" ","");

                var num = replace+""+n;

                document.getElementById('cadastro').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('cadastro').value = "Aguardando...";

                //manda a requisição dos campos para a pagina de controller
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "cliente_functionAG.php",
                    data: {
                        action: action,
                        valores: valores,
                        cod_cli: cod_cli,
                        email: email,
                        nome: nome,
                        cnpj: cnpj,
                        end: end,
                        bairro: bairro,
                        numero: numero,
                        cep: cep,
                        n:n,
                        cidade: cidade,
                        pedido: pedido
                    },
                    success: function(result){      

                        if(result == "1"){
                            $(msgbox1)
                            .html("CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO "+num)
                            .removeClass()
                            .addClass("alert alert-success")
                            .show();
                            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                            $(".cad").val('');
                            $("#field").prop("checked", false);
                            setTimeout(function()
                                {
                                    location.href="indexAG.php";

                                }, 5000);


                        }else{
                            $(msgbox)
                                .html("ERRO AO CADASTRAR")
                                .removeClass()
                                .addClass("alert alert-danger")
                                .show();
                        }

                        document.getElementById('cadastro').disabled = false;
                        document.getElementById('cadastro').value = "GERAR PEDIDO";
                    }
                });     
            }
        }
        $(msgbox).hide();
    }else {
        $(msgbox)
        .html("NÃO FOI SELECIONADO NENHUMA OPÇÃO")
        .removeClass()
        .addClass("alert alert-danger")
        .show();    
    }

}
```

Comment: Onde é feita essa contagem? Olhei o código todo e não consegui identificar onde.

Comment: seria a variavel n, na verdade é um número aleatório que vem, eu precisaria trocar isso por um contador que não repete o número

Comment: Ainda tá mt confuso isso. Vc quer que conte +1 cada vez que a função é executada?

Comment: isso, gostaria que se na ultima execução terminou em 4 na proxima continua contando no 5

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso te ajude, se puder trazer mais informações.

```js
var numeros = [];

var n = localStorage.get('n') || 0;

function SomaUm() {
 n++;
 localStorage.set('n', n);

 return numeros.push(n);
}
```